# Fetch the result from sql query group by and split them into different arrays in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

SQL: I have values in a table for 6 different categories like

```
CatName |   Value 
Cat1    |   1.23
Cat2    |   2.343
Cat3    |   3.4
Cat5    |   4.5
Cat3    |   3.1
Cat6    |   1.3
Cat4    |   2.7
```

and so on..
I need to split them as 6 different arrays based on the category name. 
I'm using ado.net to fetch the values from DB.

Comment: Add some expected result

Comment: Put all the values to List, from list you can store that in to an array. Please try some methods and post the error or outputs here